# How to open two side by side window in eclipse kepler

Tags: eclipse-kepler

Can someone tell me how to open two or more file editor in **eclipse kepler**?

In before version like helios it can be open by shortcut **ctrl + 8**.

Which looks something like this in **helios**

[image]

But in **kepler** I am not able to do this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open your file and then Window -> New Editor

I see that in Kepler this feature hasn't a shortcut **binding** anymore. You can make this yourself by going to Preferences -> General -> keys and search for "new editor". Then click Binding and press the shortcut you want.

Comment: This appears to be now out of date and no longer correct; see "achieve this indirectly" somewhere else on this page.

Answer (score 8):

You can achieve this indirectly, like first opening both the files then `click` on your `file header` in your editor and just `drag` towards the `right`.
Eclipse will automatically creates two seperate views like you have shown.

Comment: I am aware of that but it only moves window as well it takes too many efforts to adjust it vertical, as you see in image in both side I have open same file I want to do that in kepler. Now seems like kepler has remove that option.. :(

Comment: This is the correct answer (as of Sept. 2021). Don't waste your time on the others.

Answer (score 1):

Window / New Editor opens a second editor. It does not seem to have a default key binding.

When the second editor is open drag the tab to open the windows side by side.

Comment: Yes right, so I removed it but what about what I actually want?

Comment: Added second step to get windows side by side

Answer (score 0):

What command is Ctrl + 8 bound to in your workspace ? I've looked at 3.8.2 but can't find it (even though I do vaguely remember doing something like this).

Answer (score 0):

There is a way.
Window -> Editor -> Clone

Answer (score 0):

Drag out window to console and it will divide in two parts ..then put both editor side by side.